# Azure Search performance when using String vs DateTimeOffset for date values

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Do comparison filters (i.e.: between, greater, less than etc.) perform as fast on (formatted-to) string properties as they do when targeting specific data types (DateTimeOffset)?

For example, if I want to retrieve documents that have been modified after 2011-05-12, will `modifiedDateTime gt 2011-05-12T12:44:57.201Z` where `modifiedDateTime` is `DateTimeOffset` perform better than `modifiedDateTimeString gt '2011-05-12T12:44:57.201Z'` where `modifiedDateTimeString` is String type field?

And is there any azure search feature that is data-type specific to DateTimeOffset?

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you mean by range queries and comparison filters?

Comment: E.g. if i want to retrieve documents that have been modified after  2011-05-12 will 
"modifiedDateTime gt 2011-05-12T12:44:57.201Z" where modifiedDateTime is DateTimeOffset preform better than:
"modifiedDateTimeString gt '2011-05-12T12:44:57.201Z'" where modifiedDateTimeString is String type field.

Comment: Thanks. I've added your example to the question and removed "range query" as we usually mean something else when we talk about range queries. I'll have an answer posted soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that range comparisons on strings in Azure Search are not officially supported, so you should use `Edm.DateTimeOffset` to hold date/time information.

The longer answer is that range comparisons on strings will work, but only outside the context of a lambda (`any` or `all`). This was kind of an accidental feature that we decided not to remove in case people were using it, but we also decided not to advertise since the fact that it only works outside of lambdas can be confusing.

If you'd like Azure Search to support range comparisons on strings across the $filter syntax, please add a suggestion on [User Voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263029-azure-search).

Assuming that you're fine with the functional limitations of range comparisons, there is still the performance question to answer. This is not something we've benchmarked, but we can speculate a bit.

Under the hood, `Edm.DateTimeOffset` is stored in the inverted index as a long number of milliseconds since the epoch. In Lucene terms, they are queried using [NumericRangeQuery](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) instead of `TermRangeQuery`. Numeric fields are indexed using tries, which speeds up query performance versus the equivalent term range query. The [Lucene documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_3_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/NumericRangeQuery.html) is a good starting point to understand how this works if you're interested in going in depth.

> And is there any azure search feature that is data-type specific to DateTimeOffset?

Yes. The [freshness scoring function](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/add-scoring-profiles-to-a-search-index#bkmk_indexref) requires a DateTimeOffset field, and there are certain [options for interval faceting](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents#request) (day, month, year, etc.) that only apply to DateTimeOffset fields.

Comment: thank you! This is great answer, it covers everything i wanted to know. I'm dealing with some specific case where adding DateTime as String would be easier to implement, but I don't want to sacrifice performance so this helps a lot.